# Не работает запрос в базу данных. (MYSQLI)

Tags: mysql, запрос

Делаю запрос в базу данных, получаю такой ответ:

> [error] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''cName','cPhone','cEmail','cWhatForm') VALUES ('Павел',
>   '38095108' at line 1 [error_list] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [errno] =>
>   1064 [sqlstate] => 42000 [error] => You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near
>   ''cName','cPhone','cEmail','cWhatForm') VALUES ('Павел', '38095108' at
>   line 1 ) ) )

Подскажите в чем сложность данного запроса

```
$link = mysqli_connect("wi******ls", "**********", "*********", "********");
$link->query("INSERT INTO landing_client('cName','cPhone','cEmail','cWhatForm') 
              VALUES ('$name', '$phoneForSend', '$email', '$whatform')");
print_r($link);
```

Comment: Для обрамления полей в MySQL используются обратные кавычки (бэктики). Вот такие: `\``. Вы использовали прямые кавычки `'`, которыми обрамляются не имена полей, а строковые литералы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите в чем сложность данного запроса

Удалите ковычки из названий столбцов и сложность, пройдет. На этом этапе.

```
 $link->query("INSERT INTO landing_client(cName,cPhone,cEmail,cWhatForm) 
              VALUES ('$name', '$phoneForSend', '$email', '$whatform')");
```